# Getting Slider Value - d3/dc

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I am currently using dc to make a few line graphs. I also just added in a slider(i played with d3.slider, but then found a different solution)

I am hoping to use the slider to filter the other graphs. Does anyone have suggestions on how to get the selected value from the slicer, and then filter?

To filter I was thinking something like:

```
d3.select("input[type=range]").on("change", function() {
var gendersel = this.value;
});

var data = _.where(data2, {variable: gendersel});
```

However, this doesn't work...

I'm also thinking about using crossfilter (probably smarter) for filtering, but still having issues getting the slider value:

```
var bytest = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.testvar; });
bytest.filter([gendersel, gendersel + .5])
```

My Slider:

```
<div style="font-size:14px;font-family:sans-serif">Test Filter:
<input style="position:relative;top:4px;" type="range" min="1" max="2" value="1"></div>
```

I was using this as a reference:
https://www.biostat.wisc.edu/~kbroman/D3/slide_scatter.html

Answer (score 1):

var gendersel isn't in the global scope. You need to define it globally, to use it globally, and not inside the function:

```
var gendersel;
$("input[type=range]").on("change", function() { //I'm not sure what the select() thing is, I just always use $() for selectors, so if you know d3.select works, then use it.
    gendersel = this.value;
});

var data = _.where(data2, {variable: gendersel});
```

A second potential problem:
If the slider is built by Javascript, then it's possible that the element doesn't exist when this selector is created for your onchange event. If this is the case you will have to create your change event like so:

```
$(".parentOfInputs").on("change", "input[type=range]", function() {
    gendersel = $(this).value; //also not sure if in your case it should be $(this) or this. Try both.
});
```

The parentOfInputs need to be some element that already existed before the onchange event is created.

Comment: oh thanks for that tip. will `gendersel = this.value;` still update the global variable if that is just in the function?... it doesn't seem to be updating for me (but perhaps something else is amiss)

Comment: I'm going to add something to my answer.

Comment: I prefer using d3.select so you don't need to add the jQuery dependency.